# how to browse images on aws s3

Tags: image, amazon-s3

I have AWS S3 buckets full of images and was wondering how I could browse them without needing to download the whole batch first. Is there a way that I can pipe them into `feh` through `awscli` or some other method?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 can act as a web server for your images. However, it simply serves the image files when they are requested. You will need to write an application or web page that incorporates those images into a form suitable for viewing.

For example, you could list the files in the Amazon S3 bucket and then convert them into an HTML page with lots of `<img src=... />` tags. The web browser would then download the images from S3 and insert them into the web page in your browser.

If you are looking for a full-featured photo management app, try services like Prime Photos from Amazon or SmugMug. They've done all the hard work for you.

Comment: Are there any open source or no-cost available, existing tools?